# Find the number of $4 \times 4$ orthogonal matrices whose entries are either $0$ or $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, orthogonal-matrices, permutation-matrices

> Find the number of $4 \times 4$ orthogonal matrices whose entries are either $0$ or $1$.

**My solution**

It is the same as the "permutation" of the four orthonormal columns
$$\begin{pmatrix}
        1  \\
        0  \\
        0  \\
0\\
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
        0  \\
        1  \\
        0  \\
0\\
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
        0  \\
        0  \\
        1  \\
0\\
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
        0  \\
        0  \\
        0  \\
1\\
        \end{pmatrix}.$$

So the answer is $4!=24$. Could you please check my solution?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. The sum of the squares of the entries in each row must be $1$, hence each row must have exactly one entry equal to $1$, and the rest equal to $0$. Similarly for the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Perhaps that you coud have added that, since the matrix is orthogonal, no column can have only null entries and, on the other hand, if one of the entries is $1$, then all other must be equal to $0$.